# How to add row number or Serial no in angular2 datatable

Tags: javascript, database, angular, typescript, datatable

I am using angular2 -datatable.

I am not able to display correct row no.s in the corresponding rows.

The datatable starts counting from one again when the user moves to the next page using paginator.

My html code:

```
                <tbody>
                <tr  *ngFor="let item of mf.data; let i =index">
                    <td>
                        {{i+1}} 
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{item.department}}</td>
                    <td >{{item.category}}</td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `{{data.indexOf(item) + 1}}`, here I suppose `data` is the variable you bind to `<table>` by `<table [mfData]="data | filter "`

this will get the original index from array of data.

**[plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/4i93F9?p=preview)**.

Comment: I tried this. It still starts counting from 0 when I move to the next page.

Comment: Also, Is there a way to again start the counting after the ascending/ descending sorting takes place?

Comment: @mistletoe let's talk here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143950/ngx-datatable

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate it with `currentPage` (current page number) and `itemsPerPage` (number of item to show per page):

```
{{ itemsPerPage * (currentPage - 1) + i + 1 }}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering ! Although I ended up using the other solution.

Comment: I also tried this but for some reason I am not able to bind the active page  to the variable I am doing this: [(mfActivePage)]="activepage" .And then like you suggested I did this  {{ rowsOnPage * (activepage - 1) + i + 1 }}

Comment: Once you'll have correct current page number with every page the above will give you correct serial numbers.

Comment: I am not able to point out my mistake. I am using the code as per the documentation. [(mfActivePage)]="activepage" in my table element. Please   tell me if you can see where I am going wrong.